# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[BrowseBook]'

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to segue from a `collectionViewCell` to take me to a `tableView` but can't get it to work. It says

> Cannot assign value of type string to type [browseBook]

I wanna click on the cell and displays the corresponding information in the tableview cells.

CareerSectorViewController:

```
class CareerSectorViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var careerSectorViewController: UICollectionView!

        var sectors:[CareerSectorModel] = [
        CareerSectorModel(title: "Javascript", imageName: "js.png"),
        ]

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
         didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBooks", sender: self)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showBooks" {
            let destinationController = segue.destination as! BooksViewController
            if let cell = sender as? CareerSectorCell {
                if let indexPath = careerSectorViewController.indexPath(for: cell) {
                    let sector = sectors[indexPath.row]
                    destinationController.browseBooks = sector.title
                    destinationController.browseBooks = UIImage(named:sector.imageName )
                }
            }

        }

    }

   }
```

BookViewController:

```
class BooksViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     let cellIdentifier = "bookCell"

    var browseBooks:[BrowseBook] = [
        BrowseBook(image: "ruby.png", bookName: "HeadFirstRuby", authorName: "Jay McGraven"),

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return browseBooks.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier , for: indexPath) as! BookCell

        let browseBook = browseBooks[indexPath.row]

        cell.bookImageName.image = UIImage(named: browseBook.image)
        cell.nameLabel.text = browseBook.bookName
        cell.authorLabel.text = browseBook.authorName
        return cell
    }
}
```

BrowseBookModel:

```
struct BrowseBook {
    private(set) public var image: String
    private(set) public var bookName: String
    private(set) public var authorName: String

    init(image: String, bookName: String, authorName: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.authorName = authorName
    }
}
```

Comment: man, u'r trying to assign `String` to an `Array`, how can this work! Show code for `CareerSectorModel`

Comment: Can’t find a way to to the corresponding info

Comment: you don't have implementation or structure for `CareerSectorModel`?

Comment: @D4ttatraya i have it

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

```
 destinationController.browseBooks = sector.title
 destinationController.browseBooks = UIImage(named:sector.imageName )
```

with

```
destinationController.browseBooks = [BrowseBook(image: sector.imageName , bookName: sector.title, authorName: "Jay McGraven")]
```

Comment: and delete `destinationController.browseBooks = UIImage(named:sector.imageName )` this line also